# New line or line break on MapQuest Infowindow

Tags: html, mapquest

How do I insert a new lin or line break in MapQuest's InfoWindow. I have tried :

> \n
>
> \r\n
>
> `<br />`

Nothing works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<br/> should work, as in this example: poi.setInfoContentHTML('Home of the Denver <br/> Broncos');
```

Hope this helps -- not sure what is wrong otherwise.  If you post sample code, I might be able to help!

Comment: Thanks jharahush. This was my problem. I inserted the <br /> in my PHP file and when passed over to my javascript code, it gave an error. Where I now just have a PHP/XML file with the correct tags, and when gets passed to my javascript, I extract the different information from the tags and in the javascript do my <br />.